# PhpStorm + Vagrant + Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, vagrant, phpstorm

I want to display Symfony2 page using vagrant box.
If i turn on vagrant box (vagrant up), and use by ssh command "php app/console server:run" 
Then i see info " Server running on `http://127.0.0.1:8000` " 
and if i go to the website "`192.168.33.10`" or "`127.0.0.1`" or "`127.0.0.1:8000`" on host machine, Then i don't see symfony2 site.

Question: How is correctly configuration the vagrant file, that allow me see symfony2 site ?

```
Its keys lines in my vagrant file .

      ....
      config.vm.box = "symfony-v0.2.0"
      config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8000, host: 80
      config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
      config.vm.network "public_network"
      config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www/"
      ....

Add informations:
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /var/www => C:/Users/Wojtek/PhpstormProjects/DragonisProject/Symfony2Project
    default: /vagrant => C:/Users/Wojtek/PhpstormProjects/DragonisProject/Symfony2Project
```

Comment: What about `192.168.33.10:8000`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete line `config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"` from Vagrantfile.
Then start server server as `php app/console server:run 0.0.0.0:8000` it will listen to all ip addresses and access it as `http://localhost` because you have port 8000 forwarded to port 80 on host machine.

Answer (score 0):

**1) Make sure you set your local host file to point your site to the correct vagrant IP (192.168.33.10), if applicable.  Otherwise just use the IP directly.**

**2) If your vagrant instance is running, the issue is likely due to your apache conf within the vagrant box.**

Make sure you have the proper Apahce/nginx vhost in place for your site.